# mvvm architecture with smarfox in xamarin ios project

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm developing an android game using xamarin.android. Backend logic of game is hosted on smartfox server and I'm using smartfox Unity client API to consume the services.
My project architecture is: Xamarin.android -> PCL (portal class library).
Smartfox server client API is implemented within the PCL. Smartfox server keep triggering callback methods from backend and we have to capture thoe callback events and modify UI basis on that.
Now I'm unable to implement an architecture which can capture these callbacks and send it to UI. I'm able to capture callback within PCL but don;t have any idea how to forward these to UI.
Please help me out with an arch. that can fit into this particular scenario. I tried to implement triggers but don't know how to access a UI method in PCL.
You don't access UI in a PCL. PCL's are platform agnostic, so you really can't do that there.
I can think of a couple of ways to pass the data on to some UI or something controlling the UI.
Your API client could implement some Events which the UI or controller is listening to, and in here handle the event.
You could implement a MVVM pattern and through a messenger or a View Service notify the ViewModel about callbacks and manipulate the ViewModel accordingly, which then reflects in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I often use an event aggregator/messenger in these scenarios.  You don't need to adopt MVVM in order to use a messenger.  Something like [TinyMessenger](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyMessenger) might work for you.  If you do want to use MVVM, most of those frameworks will have their own messenger included.

I assume these callbacks will end up on a thread other than the UI thread, so when you get ready to modify the UI, you'll likely need to use `RunOnUIThread()` as [described here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/8289/#Comment_8289).

Comment: thanks nate but i have to use mvvm i know i have to handle these call back on uithread

Comment: Ok, yeah so like I mentioned you can use the messenger included with your MVVM framework to do the messaging then.  For instance, if you were using the MVVM Light toolkit you can use their messenger, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/d485e5b7-e6dc-4cbe-93fb-dc6311ef61a6).

Comment: Thanks nate. But Is there any example for xamarin ios which is used smartfox as back end which sends message to ios view controller.

Comment: I don't have any specific examples with that backend and messaging, no.  I've shared with you the overall architectural pattern of using an event aggregator/messenger to broadcast those callbacks/messages throughout your app.  If you try to hook it up using your MVVM framework and post the code here (if you have issues), people may be able to help further.